# Can't update nested data in a collection using multiple conditions and ids

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I tried so much to find and update multiple data using multiple query conditions and many ids. However, I'm not getting the expected result. It updates only one item every time. What's wrong with the code? Please help.

```
 await Restaurants.updateMany({ "_id": req.order.restaurant, "items._id": { $in: items } }, { $set: {"items.$.enabled" : false }}, {multi: true})
```

Even I tried to first find the doc using the find method. But in that case, it returns only one item.

in `req.order.restaurant` there is the id of the restaurant and in the `items` there is an array of ids.

However,

In another collection, I also have to update the same data. There I was able to do that.

```
await RestaurantFoodItems.updateMany({ "_id": { $in: items } }, { $set: { enabled: false } }, {multi: true})
```

Here it worked. And also was able to find multiple doc using the find method.

Comment: When `$` update operator is used, the update happens for the first matching element (only one element gets updated). Try using other array update operators to update multiple array elements.

Comment: But it worked when I tried to update data from another collection. `RestaurantFoodItems.updateMany({ "_id": { $in: items } }, { $set: { enabled: false } }, {multi: true})` ----- Here it worked

Comment: Because thats not an array field. The `$` operator is used with array fields only.

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't get you. The `items` var is also an array here.

Comment: `{ "_id": { $in: items } }` - thats a query filter - not an update operation.

Comment: oh, Okay, I got it.

Comment: So, what else I can use here? Have you any idea about it?

Comment: You can refer the docs about array update operators: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/#array

Comment: wow, It's worked now. I've been working on this for almost 3 hours. Thanks you so much again.

Answer (score 0):

I just have to use `{ $set: {"items.$.[]enabled" : false }}` an extra `[]` as you can see. Thank you so much @
prasad_. It's used for updating multiple documents.